# Pasting CSS from devtools creates multiple lines

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome dev tools to style elements on the fly. Since updating to the latest version of Chrome (Version 95.0.4638.54) I'm unable to paste a single line of css copied from the developer tools.

When pasting, instead of

```
left: -60 px;
top: -25px;
```

I'm getting

```
    left: -60
px
;
    top: -25
px
;
```

I haven't changed any Chrome settings so I'm wondering if anyone else is having this problem or might this be bug?

Comment: It's a bug in devtools, https://crbug.com/1259088, fixed in Canary.

Comment: It happens even when not using the length tool so I hope they fix it accordingly.

Comment: wOxxOm please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As wOxxOm mentioned, it's a bug, so in the meantime you can just user something like a [CSS Beautifier](https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/)!

Comment: CSS Beautifier will not fix it.

Comment: @ViliusL I'm sorry, what?  I literally took the CSS in this question and pasted it into the beautifier.  It put out "properly" formatted CSS.  My answer was a workaround because it was confirmed to be a bug.

Comment: Maybe it will work with sometimes, but in most cases result will be invalid code, for example: `left: -60 px ;`

Comment: I tried CSS Beautifier with the direct result from Chrome dev tools and it seems to work for me. Perhaps it saves but a few valuable seconds!

Comment: @ViliusL So I must have copied something wrong cause I just replicated your issue.  Must be in some rare cases but it seems for most of them it works.  I've done odd spaces and line breaks and it pieced everything together.  But it's *an* option.  Assuming this wasn't a chrome bug I wonder what better options there would be.  Other than writing your own.